# Hide column in WPF grid

Tags: wpf, gridview, grid, contextmenu

I have a grid like this:

```
<Grid Name="mainPane">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Hide" Click="MenuItemHide_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="576*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridView x:Name="permitsCol">
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="colPermitSeq" Header="Permit Seq">
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

I have one grid and I have declared one column. I add more columns during runtime.

I would like to have a right-mouse-button-menu (contextmenu) to hide/remove a column.

What do I need to do to get that column hidden?

Comment: I have rephrased your question, please revert if you think your question isn't the same anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, try to bind this to ColumnHeaderStyle of DataGrid

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultColumnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
  <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
</Style>

<ContextMenu  x:Key="RowMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   <MenuItem Header="Hide" Click="MenuItemHide_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Im not sure how this is going to help me?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide a column, for example `colPermitSeq`, you can use:

```
colPermitSeq.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
```

You can also set it to `Collapse` if that's more convienent.

As for deleting, the `RemoveAt` method of Grid.ColumnDefinitions deletes a column at the given position.

```
DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(3);
```

The `Clear` method of Grid.ColumnDefinitions deletes all columns in a Grid.

```
DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
```